# Loading dynamic links based on state

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm having trouble rendering a dynamic ReactRouter menu.

I have a component, `<MyApp />`. In the `componentDidMount()` method of `<MyApp />`, i'm calling an API. the API returns an array of articles. I then set the state of `<MyApp />` with these new articles.

```
.....
this.setState({
  isLoaded: true,
  articles: result
});
```

Now, I load a new component,  `<ArticlePage articles={this.state.articles} />`

Slight tangent - This new `<ArticlePage />` is made with a function component, not a class component.  The reason being, is I had trouble using ReactRouter inside Class components.

`function ArticlePage(props){}...` now exists. Props holds my array of articles.

Inside `ArticlePage()`, i want to create a reactRouter link for each of the articles in the array that i'm passing in as props. This is where i'm having trouble.

In my head, I need to loop over each of the `props.articles` array elements, and create a reactRouter link element..

```
<ul>
{props.articles.map(item => 
(
  <li>
    <Link to={`${url}/${item.article_id}`}>{item.title}</Link>
  </li>
))}
</ul>
```

The problem is, my links are not being displayed on the page. Debugging suggests that when the page renders and the .map loop above runs, the array is empty. Using Chrome developer tools, I can see that the props.article for that component does in deed contain all the articles. However, i am of course looking at this object in slower time than when the page renders, so it has had time to complete.

What is it, that I am doing wrong? Perhaps I should be loading and passing the articles state in a different way?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Without seeing the full code, my guess is that the original, empty array is being passed down to `<ArticlePage />`. If that's the case, you could wait until the array is populated to render the component.

Comment: Yes, I described that above. From the <MyApp/> component. How do I “wait”?

Comment: You could do something like `{props.articles.length > 0 && props.articles.map(...)}`